# The equivalents of abc.Sequence in Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, code-conversion

I need to convert to some Python 3 code to Python 2 code

```
from collections.abc import Sequence

def to_tensor(X, device):
  .....
    if isinstance(X, (list, tuple)):
        return [to_tensor_(x) for x in X]

    if isinstance(X,Sequence):<-------equals to if isinstance(X,(str,bytes))?
        X = torch.tensor(np.array(X))

    return X.to(device)
```

as you can see above, I want to know whether:

```
isinstance(X,Sequence)
```

equals to

```
isinstance(X,(str,bytes))
```

and [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence)
does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no, it's not equivalent.

Longest answer:

First, Python2 has no "bytes" type - Python3 `bytes` are Python2 `str` and Python3 `str` is Python2 `unicode`, so the right question would be: is `isinstance(X,Sequence)` equivalent to `isinstance(X, (unicode, str))`.

Then, the answer is *still* no. Py3 `str` and `bytes` ARE instances of `abc.Sequence` indeed, **but** so are any instances of a class implementing `abc.Sequence`, so you can have objects that are `Sequence` without being `str` or `bytes` ((Django orm's `Queryset` class would be a perfect candidate).

> and this doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence make not no sense to me

If you follow the link in this doc, [you get a verbal definition](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) of what a "sequence" is:

> An iterable which supports efficient element access using integer
>   indices via the **getitem**() special method and defines a **len**()
>   method that returns the length of the sequence
>   (..)
>   Note that dict also supports **getitem**() and **len**(), but is considered a mapping rather than a sequence

According to this definition, to test if an object is a sequence, you have to test whether it's iterable, have a `__getitem__` and a `__len_` method and is not a `dict`. This won't be an *exact* equivalent of the py3 code, but it's the closer you can get (at least without more context, cf below):

```
def is_sequence(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return False

    if not (
        hasattr(obj, "__getitem__") 
        and hasattr(obj, "__len__")
        ): 
        return False

    # we might have false postive here
    # with dict-likes not inheriting from
    # `dict`, so we also weed out objects 
    # having a `keys()` methods which
    # are most likely dict-likes
    if hasattr(obj, "keys"):
        return False
    return True
```

Now the real answer to your problem might be a bit different: there's the (more or les) formal definition of what a "sequence" is, and there's the context in which the code you're porting is called and the author's intent.

The author might have assumed that his function would only ever be passed lists, tuples, strings or bytes, in which case the test intent was indeed a misguided (I'd even say broken) and undocumented attempt to check for strings and bytes.

Or the author might have assumed that his function would just never be passed a string or bytes, but then I can't understand why he would treat lists and tuples differently from other sequences.

To make a long story short: you will have to study the context,  or eventually ask the author for clarification - if possible, of course.